# Trying to install MongoDB PHP Driver in Elastic Beanstalk Amazon Linux

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-5.6

Trying to install MongoDB PHP Driver in Elastic Beanstalk running Amazon Linux. Have already created a config file in the .ebextensions folder with the following code:

```
container_commands:
  01installMongoExtension:
    command: 'printf "\n" | pecl install -f mongo'
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Getting an error of:

```
Application deployment failed at 2018-11-06T20:01:32Z with exit status 2 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh failed.
```

with the following:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter[1.1.3].
- alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
Problem 2
- Installation request for mongodb/mongodb 1.1.2 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.1.2].
- mongodb/mongodb 1.1.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
Problem 3
- alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.6.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.6.7 -> satisfiable by alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter[1.1.3].
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.6.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.6.0].
```

Not sure where to go from here, seeing as the config file should install the driver...

Would like to add that I see the files from the repo that Jenkins builds the app within the `/var/app/ondeck/` directory.

Comment: Hmm. That should be `pecl mongodb` as the `mongo` package is deprecated and the dependency error is in fact saying `ext-mongodb`, which is of course the newer package. You likely would get a message about the deprecation if the `ignoreErrors` was removed as well. Also please read **ALL** the documentation reference [MongoDB PHP Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/) since the confusion over the multiple dependency install is really quite common.

Comment: Okay I will try that but the interesting thing is when I look into cat `/var/log/awslogs.log` the install command doesn't even run. Is there a way to have Beanstalk run the `.ebextensions` config file before Composer tries to install it's dependencies?  -- Does that even make sense?

Comment: Possibly not. But the main point is it's the "wrong package". And as I noted you're "ignoring errors" so having nothing in the log is not surprising.

Comment: Thank you, I will remove that ignore command and see if anything comes up.

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://codinglatte.com/posts/php/php-7-with-mongodb-to-elastic-beanstalk/

You need to use `pecl7` instead of `pecl`

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research I found working solution for for php 7+

```
commands:
 01installMongoExtension:
  command:  /usr/bin/yes 'no'| /usr/bin/pecl7 install mongodb
  test: '! /usr/bin/pecl7 info mongodb'
```

create .ebextensions folder on root. Inside that folder create php7-mongodb-driver.config file and paste above code in that.